# NullPointerException в while(!=null) IEnumerator

Tags: c#, ienumerator

Решил сделать реализацию `LinkedList`, используя `IEnumerable`. Проблема как раз-таки в нем.
У меня есть метод `Contains(..)`,где при использовании foreach исключений не возникает. Есть метод `AddAfter(..)`, где исключение возникает.
Меня сбивают с толку две вещи:

1. Исключение возникает в цикле while(currentNode!=null) (но вылет происходит при currentNode==null)
2. Программа не вылетает при запуске без отладки, хотя в настройках исключений сказано "прерывать работу"

Вот эти функции:

```
public IEnumerator <T> GetEnumerator()
{
    currentNode = firstNode;
    while (currentNode != null)
    {
        yield return currentNode.Data;
        currentNode = currentNode.Next;
    }
}

public bool Contains(T item)
{
    foreach (var t in this)
    {
        if (t.Equals(item))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public bool AddAfter(T item, T after)
{
    if (this.Contains(item))
    {
        return false;
    }

    foreach (var t in this) // где-то здесь вылетает
    {
        if (t.Equals(after))
        {
            currentNode.Next = new Node <T>(item, currentNode, currentNode.Next);
            if (currentNode == lastNode)
                lastNode = lastNode.Next;
            return true;
        }
    }

    lastNode.Next = new Node <T>(item, lastNode, null);
    lastNode      = lastNode.Next;
    return true;
}
```

Отладчик проходит `Contains()` без вопросов, но на `foreach` показывает проблему.
В режиме без отладки NullPointerException программу не останавливает(или просто не появляется), и она спокойно перешагивает `foreach`, и появляются неверные данные.
Может, я как-то не правильно понимаю `yield return`? 
Я так понимаю, что при первом заходе в функцию выполнятся все строки до `yield return`. При втором выполнится строка за `yield`, и программа пойдет дальше по циклу. Тогда выходит, что currentNode между заходами обнуляется?

Вылет: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Настройки исключений: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это еще не все. Если запустить отладку, но при этом пошагово не заходить в этот проблемный `foreach`, то, опять же, исключений не возникает, и программа выводит как раз-таки ожидаемые результаты. Но если при отладке зайди в этот `foreach`, то будет исключение, как на втором скриншоте. Как это вообще работает?

Заполняю я весь этот список так:

```
var tb = TextField; // textBox

var list = new MyGenListUnique <int>();
list.AddRange(new []{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7});
tb.AppendText(list.ToString() + Environment.NewLine); 

list.AddAfter(-12, 2); // {0,1,2, -12, 3,4,5,6,7} // проблема здесь
tb.AppendText(list.ToString() + Environment.NewLine);
```

Вот функции добавления и связанные с ними:

```
public int AddRange(T[] items)
{
    if (items is null)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    var countAdded = 0;
    foreach (var t in items)
    {
        var currCount = Count;
        Add(t);
        if (currCount > Count)
            countAdded++;
    }

    return countAdded;
}

public void Add(T item)
{
    if (firstNode is null)
    {
        firstNode = new Node <T>(item, null, null);
        lastNode  = firstNode;
        return ;
    }

    if (!this.Contains(item))
    {
        lastNode.Next = new Node <T>(item, lastNode, null);
        lastNode      = lastNode.Next;
        IncreaseCount();
        return ;                
    }
}

public new string ToString()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder(100);
    sb.Append("{ ");
    foreach (var t in this)
    {
        sb.Append(t + " ");
    }

    sb.Append("}");

    return sb.ToString();
}

private void IncreaseCount(int count = 1)
{
    Count += count;
}
```

`Count` - `autoproperty`, конструктор по умолчанию - пустой.
Если что, вот класс `Node<T>`

```
private class Node <T>
{ 
    public T Data;
    public Node <T> Next { get; set; }

    public Node <T> Prev { get; set; }

    public Node() {}
    public Node(T data, Node <T> prev, Node <T> next)
    {
        Data = data;
        Next = next;
        Prev = prev;
    }  
}
```

Comment: добавь еще пример код где ты все это заполняешь и вызываешь. Зачем тебе нужно поле `currentNode`? Ошибки скорее всего из-за того, что оно общее и меняется во всех этих функциях

Comment: Что ж, частично ответ найден. Если приписать в этой проблемной функции в конце строку  'currentNode = firstNode;', то все вроде ок. Но я все равно не совсем понимаю механику этого. И главное, почему исключение не возникает, если не заходить отладчиком в сам метод GetEnumerator.

Comment: возможно отладчик сначала присваивает currentNode = currentNode.Next; потом при наведении курсора заново расчитать currentNode.Next, если currentNode стало null выдаёт ошибку.
если в нормальном запуске всё нормально рабоает, а код вроде правильный, просто игнорируй

Comment: Пока что я так и делаю. Но если есть что-то, механику чего не понимаешь, то это потом выливается в гораздо большие проблемы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут всё просто же. У вас вызов `GetEnumerator()` использует одну и ту же переменную `currentNode` на каждом вызове, что является ошибкой, так как разные перечислители должны быть независимы.

При запуске без отладчика это не приводит ни к каким последствиям, потому что вы не вызываете `GetEnumerator` несколько раз.

А вот при запуске под отладчиком отладчик сам вызывает `GetEnumerator()`, чтобы показать вам значение переменной `this`. Точнее, студия вызывает `ToString()`, который у вас сделан через `GetEnumerator()` - но и вызов `GetEnumerator()` тоже можно себе представить.

Отсюда мораль: пишите менее запутанный код, и всегда будьте готовыми, что объявленный как `public` метод кто-нибудь да вызовет.

Конкретно в вашем коде для исправления ошибки надо сделать `currentNode` локальной переменной. А цикл `foreach (var t in this)` заменить на вот такой:

```
for (var currentNode = firstNode; currentNode != null; currentNode = currentNode.Next) 
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: 0xdb, какой из причин разделения сложного союза запятой вы воспользовались? Логического ударения на слово "потому" я точно не ставил :-)

Answer (score 0):

Что ж, у меня была выключена оптимизация в свойствах проекта. Включил ее - и все хорошо, поведение во время отладки соответствует поведению без отладки. Очень жаль, что это может иметь значение.